# SQL perform AVG of a column every X rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I have a table that has the following (relevant) columns: id_mi, date and value.
I want to build a graph using the values in the "value" column in the y axis and the dates in the x axis, but since they are a lot I would like that the points on my graph were the average of X rows.

Let's say X = 10 for this example:

What I'm trying to do is to get the first 10 values on my table, calculate the average value and store it in a row, than the following row will contain the average of the values from 11 to 20 and so on.

Basically I need to "compress" 10 rows in a single one that has the average value for the "value" column.

I'm using Postgres 9.2

Comment: would a ms sql solution help?

Comment: If the ms sql solution is in someway supported by postgres 9.2 syntax than yes :) because I'm required to use postgres

Comment: Do you have an auto increment key?

Comment: Yes, we have the primary key of the table (id_mi) that autoincrements

Comment: Where presumably, it's the `date` column that defines the order in which rows should be considered, in order for "first", "next" etc to be defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the window functions:

```
select avg(value) over (order by date
                        rows between 9 preceding and current row) as MovingAvg10
from t;
```

If you wanted to be sure that you start on the 10th row, you could do:

```
select (case when row_number() over (order by date) >= 10
             then avg(value) over (order by date
                                   rows between 9 preceding and current row
                                  )
        end) as MovingAvg10
from t;
```

EDIT:

Your revised question is much easier:

```
select ((seqnum - 1) / 10) as whichgroup, avg(value)
from (select row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum, t.*
      from table t
     ) t
group by ((seqnum - 1) / 10)
order by 1;
```

Postgres does integer division, but if you wanted to be explicit, you could do:  `trunc((seqnum - 1) / 10)` to get the group number.

Comment: The point is that doing what you say the window moves one by one, so the first time i have a window that is 1-10, the second time 2-11, 3-13 and so on. What i want is a window that moves 10 by 10, so the first time the avg is between rows 1-10, the second time 11-20, 21-30 and so on.
The second piece of code if i'm correct starts to perform the average computation starting with the 10th row

Comment: btw I think that the "range" keyword must be removed since the postgres documentation says to choose between range and rows:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS

Comment: @MastErAldo . . . I removed the `range` keyword.